# String similarity efficiency in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, similarity, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-dataset

We are new to Apache spark and we are doing String matching using string similarity techniques(JaroWinkler, Levenshtein, Cosine),
we have to do this to a huge data(2.2 million), wanted to know if this is the right way or if we can make it even more efficient in any way ?

```
    package org.sparkexample;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
    import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

    import info.debatty.java.stringsimilarity.JaroWinkler;
    import info.debatty.java.stringsimilarity.Levenshtein;

    public class StringSimilarity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutils");
          JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("JoinFunctions").setMaster("local[*]"));
          SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
          SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("StringSimiliarityExample").getOrCreate();

             JaroWinkler jw = new JaroWinkler();
             Levenshtein Levenshtein1=new Levenshtein();

            Dataset<Row> sourceFileContent = sqlContext.read()
                        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                        .option("header", "true")
                        .load("Source.csv");

            Dataset<Row> targetFileContent = sqlContext.read()
                        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                        .option("header", "true")
                        .load("Target.csv");

              List<Row> targetFileContentList = targetFileContent.collectAsList();
              for(Row individaulRow : targetFileContentList){
                    productDescriptionSource=productDescriptionTarget=brandSource=brandTarget=manufacturerIDSource=manufacturerIDTarget="";

                    productDescriptionSourceIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("productDescription");
                    productDescriptionTargetIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("productDescriptionTarget");

                    manufacturerIDSourceIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("Manufacturer part Number");
                    manufacturerIDTargetIndex=individaulRow.fieldIndex("Manufacturer part NumberTarget");


                    if(!individaulRow.isNullAt(productDescriptionSourceIndex)){
                        productDescriptionSource=individaulRow.get(productDescriptionSourceIndex).toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s+]", "");              
                    }
                    if(!individaulRow.isNullAt(productDescriptionTargetIndex)){
                        productDescriptionTarget=individaulRow.get(productDescriptionTargetIndex).toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s+]", "");              
                    }

                    if(!individaulRow.isNullAt(manufacturerIDSourceIndex)){
                        manufacturerIDSource=individaulRow.get(manufacturerIDSourceIndex).toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s+]", "");              
                    }
                    if(!individaulRow.isNullAt(manufacturerIDTargetIndex)){
                        manufacturerIDTarget=individaulRow.get(manufacturerIDTargetIndex).toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s+]", "");              
                    }

                    /* STRING SIMILARITY */             
                    Row individualObject= (Row)RowFactory.create(
                            isMatchValue+" ",
                            "1:"+String.format("%.4f",jaroWinkler.similarity(productDescriptionSource, productDescriptionTarget)),
                            "2:"+String.format("%.4f",levenshtein.similarity(manufacturerIDSource, manufacturerIDTarget)),
                            );
                    trainSetData.add(individualObject);
                }
    Dataset<Row> machineLearningDataSet = sparkSession.createDataFrame(trainSetData, schemaTrainSetData);           

     }

    }
```

For the above code it takes 30 min to run for 1 Million data(Standalone System).

Comment: The code your show is actually a **non use* of Spark (well, except for the CSV readers). You never distribute any calculation, as you use collectData() as an entry point, and the goal of collect data is to bring back all data from Spark back to the driver (locally). You should step back and read an introduction to Spark/Spark SQL. (E.g. if you use Spark RDDs, use map() to transform the data, if you use Spark SQL, read how to apply UDF, user defined functions, ...). As it stands, this question is not a good fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: I would recommend that you use stringmetric package since its written in Scala. I think it would be faster.https://github.com/rockymadden/stringmetric.

I see you could you could make the computation faster by

a) Scaleing Out

b) Tune + add memory/cups spark parameters

c) Also writing code in scala using dataframe api.

Comment: @KrishnaKalyan that lib looks interesting. I'll take a look at it but the OPs question is in Java.

Comment: For others looking for a string similarity in Spark, there is a Spark function levenshtein: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#levenshtein-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-